# Error when importing seasonal_decompose from statsmodels

Tags: python, python-3.x, statsmodels

I am working inside of a jupyter notebook, and am trying to import the seasonal_decompose function from the statsmodels package.

This is the code that I wrote to get the import:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
```

When I run this code in my notebook, this is the warning I am getting:

```
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:219: RuntimeWarning: scipy._lib.messagestream.MessageStream size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 56 from C header, got 64 from PyObject
```

Could someone please explain what this warning means and how I can fix it?

Comment: I also saw this message when trying "import textblob". As it seemed to relate to scipy, I checked & found my scipy version wasn't current.  Upgrading to scipy 1.9 fixed this . You may want to look at your version of scipy.